# Need help converting ANTLR grammar to pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a project, which is still embryonic, where I'm attempting to write wiki parsers using real grammars.  I found a [Creole grammar](http://dirkriehle.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/creole10_with_extension.g) that seems to be reasonably complete, and confirmed by third parties to work (with ANTLR).

I've started moving things forwards, however hit a few hurdles which I'm assuming a common stumbling blocks with pyparsing.

```
escaped
    :   ESCAPE  STAR  STAR
    |   ESCAPE  .
    // '.' in a parser rule means arbitrary token, not character
    ;
```

What I came up with for this was:

```
ESCAPE = Literal('~')
STAR = Literal('*')
escaped = ESCAPE + STAR + STAR | ESCAPE + Word(printables, max=1)
```

I couldn't find anything else in pyparsing to match a single character, but this seems to work.  However when looking at the header content, I have this sub-expression:

```
heading_content
    :   heading_markup  heading_content  ( heading_markup )?
    |   ( ~( EQUAL | ESCAPE | NEWLINE | EOF ) | escaped )+
    ;
```

I'm using a Forward, but for the second part, I ended up with:

```
OneOrMore(CharsNotIn("=~\r\n") | escaped)('heading_content')
```

Now this matches "test" and "test~=" but not "test~=foo" where it only matches the "test" part.  Why is that?

Secondly I was wondering if there was another way to specify the content part other than CharsNotIn?

Now the bit that really has me stumped is trying to match the unformatted text part.  This is core to matching all sorts of plain text.  Now the grammar specifies:

```
text_unformatted
  : ( ~(  ITAL
        |   STAR
        |   LINK_OPEN
        |   IMAGE_OPEN
        |   NOWIKI_OPEN
        |   EXTENSION
        |   FORCED_LINEBREAK
        |   ESCAPE
        |   NEWLINE
        |   EOF )
    |  forced_linebreak 
    |  escaped )+
```

This is where I've hit a wall.  Now the simple bits above are defined as:

```
# STAR, ESCAPE and escaped defined above
ITAL = Literal('//')
LINK_OPEN = Literal('[[')
IMAGE_OPEN = Literal('{{')
NOWIKI_OPEN = Literal('{{{')
EXTENSION = Literal('@@')
FORCED_LINEBREAK = Literal(r'\\')
CR = Literal('\r')
LF = Literal('\n')
NEWLINE = Optional(CR) + LF | CR
```

However my naive approaches of OneOrMore(NotAny(...) | FORCED_LINEBREAK | escaped) didn't work, and ended up looping infinitely.  Reading the docs a little more showed that NotAny doesn't actually return any matches.  So how do we match this?  I can't use CharNotIn(...) because a single '{' is entirely valid.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago, I wrote a converter written in pyparsing for antlr grammars, that might be helpful, I submitted it as a feature request in pyparsing tickets :

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3060671&group_id=97203&atid=617314

The antlr grammar is almost complete, so it might do the job, otherwise, it could be a source of useful information for how to have pyparsing equivalence for antlr grammars, it includes some tests too.

Hope it helps :-)